# Wie sagt man »facetime«?

Tags: translation

> Hallo, Jana! Willst du facetimen?
>
> Hello, Jana! Do you want to facetime?

Ich weiß nicht, ob das Verb »facetimen« existiert. Das habe ich mir ausgedacht. Habt ihr Vorschläge? Danke!

Comment: *To facetime* as in "using the chat service provided by Apple inc." or something different?

Comment: Yes. Its like talking to a person face to face

Comment: Ich schlage vor, die Information, dass es sich bei *FaceTime* um einen Chat-Service handelt, zur Frage hinzuzufügen. Während ich seit Jahren mit MSN, Skype, ICQ, Yahoo! Instant Messenger, AIM, Jabber, Facebook, HipChat und WhatsApp umgehe, durch Freunde auch von der Existenz von Gadu-Gadu, QQ, WeChat, Line und Kik weiß, hatte ich, bevor ich die Frage gelesen habe, noch nie von "FaceTime" gehört und war dahingehend erst mal verwirrt, bis ich die Kommentare gelesen habe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ich denke, "Facetimen" darf wohl verwendet werden, analog zu "Googeln" und "Skypen", etc., zumindest in der gesprochenen Sprache: Derartige Worte verbreiten sich, da sie kürzer sind als die verfügbaren Varianten in de roffiziellen Standardsprache, und gut verstanden werden, insbesondere, wenn der Kontext wenig Raum für Missverständnisse lässt.
Die "offiziell korrekte" Version wäre wahrscheinlich "Hast Du Lust, Dich mit mir über Facetime zu unterhalten?".

Comment: Das ist aber interessant

Comment: Und im Gegensatz zu I-C-Q-en oder M-S-N-en lässt sich facetimen wie skypen ordentlich aussprechen. Jabbern oder was es sonst noch so gibt, war wahrscheinlich nie ausreichend verbreitet. Whatsappen geht übrigens auch.

Answer (score 2):

Es gibt Belege dass der Begriff *facetimen* benutzt wird:

Zwar nicht bei [Duden](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/facetimen), aber [bei ehow](http://www.ehow.de/man-androidhandy-facetimen-info_5105/). Auch Google kennt den Suchbegriff, auch als "facetimen ohne W-Lan" oder "facetimen iPhone".

Ob es damit ein "existierendes" Verb ist wage ich an dieser Stelle nicht zu beurteilen, wann eine Neuschöpfung ein "Wort" ist wurde hier und anderswo schon diskutiert. *Verstanden* wird es ziemlich sicher zumindest von allen, die [FaceTime](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/FaceTime) kennen.

Allgemein gesagt kann man *facetimen* analog zu *skypen* betrachten, wobei letzteres es schon in den [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/skypen) geschafft hat.

Comment: Ist »*facetimen*« ein existierendes Wort? Was für eine Frage! Ja, natürlich. Es steht ja da. Jemand hat es geschrieben, also existiert es. Ist es sinnvoll? Ja! Es ist mindestens gleich gut verständlich wie »aufbänken« oder »Titer«. Jeder Facetime-User wird das Wort auf Anhieb verstehen. Das nicht jeder Mensch Facetime kennt, macht nichts. Wer Orgel spielt wird das Wort »gedackt« kennen, jeder Chemiker weis was »titrieren« ist, und die »Laktatschwelle« ist unter Läufern wohlbekannt. Jede Gruppe hat ihre eigenen Fachbegriffe, die andere Menschen möglicherweise nicht gleich verstehen.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast - Ich stimme Dir voll zu, wollte aber keine Debatte aufmachen... Puristen gegen Reformer Konservative gegen Neuerer oder was auch immer ;-)